# Вывод репорта в веб-форму на основе sql-таблицы

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

Здравствуйте.

Есть `sqlserver` таблица `SQLQuery3.sql` с параметрами `DECLARE @pcod varchar(30)`, `@mcode varchar(5)`.

Нужно вывести на ее основе репорт на веб-форму visual studio 2010 C#. Уже создал все соответствующие формы для вывода, а вот как написать, чтобы выводилась именно моя таблица на подготовленную форму, не понимаю.

Можно ли это сделать, и если да то как?
Спасибо.

**Обновление**

Моя задача - на основе параметризованного sql запроса сделать report на веб форме в visual studio на с#. Посмотрев все, что я понял, я создал форму с репортом и форму, в которой будет пользователь вводить данные (параметр запроса) и, соответсвенно, с ним выводится нужные строки из моего запроса. И теперь я пытаюсь это сделать. Мне бы хотя бы какую-то структуру того, как это можно сделать или то, что надо почитать, так как на данный момент я ничего не понимаю.

Comment: @Andy92, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: @Чад, исправил замечания.

Comment: Попробуй через мастер отчетов(ReportViewer), наверное самый простой путь!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вам надо:

1. Получить данные из таблицы.
2. Наполнить этими данными формы.

Есть другой вариант, насколько я помню:

1. Это описать датасурс.
2. связать элементы формы с датасурсом.

Вам что именно то не понятно? Говорю сразу, код писать не буду, могу только концепцию рассказать.

Comment: Да мне, если честно, почти все непонятно. Как, например, привязать таблицу так, чтобы выводилось именно то, что указано в параметре?

Answer (score 0):

У вас в голове явно какая-то ужасная путаница, вследствие чего не очень понятно, что именно у вас есть.  SQLQuery3.sql  - это явно не таблица, а некий файл, содержащий, вероятно, sql-запрос (возможно, для создания этой самой таблицы)

DECLARE @pcod varchar(30) , @mcode varchar(5)  - это явно какой-то вырванный из контекста кусок sql-запроса, по которому нельзя в полной мере судить о вашей структуре данных. Пожалуйста , формулируйте ваш вопрос более правильно, и, вполне возможно, вам смогут помочь.

**Обновление**

Вы все какими-то очень уж общими формулировками пишете, слишком обтекаемо. Вы пожалуйста конкретно напишите, что именно вам нужно сделать, о каких конкретно технологиях/фреймворках идет речь, опишите структуру ваших данных, укажите, что конкретно вы сделали и что конкретно не получается. А общие формулировки - они хороши для студентов, плавающих на экзамене и пытающихся вытянуть на тройку.

Comment: Обновил вопрос

Comment: Уже нашел ответ на свой вопрос. И других формулировок, кроме общих, у меня, к сожалению, не было.